# UITextView in Xcode Interface Builder preview is messed up

Tags: xcode, xcode5.1

So I've seen an annoyance in Xcode 5.1.  When adding a TextView i often get into a state where it doesn't display all the text

[image]

When I double click it to allow me to edit the text I can see it fine.  Does anybody know what could be causing this

[image]

Comment: If it's merely a storyboard display bug, report it to Apple and keep working around it until they fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is caused by Xcode bugginess. Since it's merely a storyboard display bug, report it to Apple and keep working around it until they fix it.